# Powershell: Lag function over property

Tags: powershell

Hoi everybody,

I am looking, whether there is the possibility to implement a lag function - without having to iterate over the whole list, e.g., look  at the following example:

```
$input = '[
    { "user_id":"1", "earned":"100", "valid_at": "20200101"},
    { "user_id":"1", "earned":"200", "valid_at": "20200102"},
    { "user_id":"1", "earned":"10", "valid_at": "20200103"},
    { "user_id":"2", "earned":"10", "valid_at": "20200101"},
    { "user_id":"2", "earned":"40", "valid_at": "20200103"},
    { "user_id":"3", "earned":"400", "valid_at": "20200101"},
    { "user_id":"3", "earned": null, "valid_at": "20200102"},
    { "user_id":"3", "earned": "20", "valid_at": "20200103"}
]'

$expected_output = '[
    { "user_id":"1", "earned":"100", "valid_at": "20200101", "last_earned":null},
    { "user_id":"1", "earned":"200", "valid_at": "20200102", "last_earned":"100"},
    { "user_id":"1", "earned":"10", "valid_at": "20200103", "last_earned":"200"},
    { "user_id":"2", "earned":"10", "valid_at": "20200101", "last_earned":null},
    { "user_id":"2", "earned":"40", "valid_at": "20200103", "last_earned":"10"},
    { "user_id":"3", "earned":"400", "valid_at": "20200101", "last_earned":null},
    { "user_id":"3", "earned": null, "valid_at": "20200102", "last_earned":"400"},
    { "user_id":"3", "earned": "20", "valid_at": "20200103", "last_earned":null}
]'

$json_input = ConvertFrom-Json –InputObject $input

$expected_json_output = ConvertFrom-Json –InputObject $expected_output
```

This creates the following input:

[image]

Together with the following expected output:

[image]

Now my questions are:

- Is there a way to programmatically build the *last_earned* column, without having to iterate over the whole list (i.e., somehow with Group-Object or Where-Object?
- Currently, I am iterating over the whole list - but had to realize quickly, that, while it works as expected, it is very inefficient if you have a lot of records to compute this over
- I am currently computing this separately for each individual *user_id* (i.e.,

  - selecting it,
  - ordering the result and then
  - checking for the last earned

Comment: Show us your code :)

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve....

Comment: One option is to use group-object on userid and partition the big list into lots of small lists, then you can process each small list and re-assemble into the desired output by combining the groups of output items. Alternatively, if your input list is guaranteed to be sorted, just “foreach()” over the input and copy the previous “earned” into the current “last_earned”, except if the userid has changed, in which case set “last_earned” to null. If you post your current code we can see which of those approaches might be appropriate (if any)...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is already sorted, you can accomplish this in a single pass by keeping track of the last seen value per user id with a hashtable:

```
$last = @{}
$json_input |Select-Object *,@{Name='earned_day_before';Expression={$last[$_.user_id];$last[$_.user_id]=$_.earned}}
```

---

If not, you can sort all records first by user id, then date:

```
$last = @{}
$json_input |Sort-Object user_id,valid_at |Select-Object *,@{Name='earned_day_before';Expression={$last[$_.user_id];$last[$_.user_id]=$_.earned}}
```